# probit regression in keras

Tags: python, keras, classification

I've been playing around with activation functions for a binary classification model in keras.  For example, I've implemented a logit model with `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`, and I've implemented a cloglog model as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
np.random.seed(42)

# Some Data
nrows = 1000
ncols = 20
X = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) - 0.5
CF = np.random.rand(ncols, 1)
y = np.sign(X.dot(CF))
y[np.where(y == -1)] = 0

# cloglog model
def cloglog(x):
    return -(K.exp(-K.exp(x))-1)

input = Input(shape=(ncols,))
output = Dense(1, activation=cloglog)(input)
model = Model(input, output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

I'd really like to try out a probit model, but I'm struggling to implement the link function with just the operations available in `keras.backend`.

Is this going to be possible? Or do I really need the distribution functions (pdf/cdf) available in `scipy`?

Comment: Interesting question!  The challenge seems to be the fact that there is no analytical formula for the CDF of the Gaussian distribution.  I think we need to approximate it with tensor operations using findings from academic works. E.g.
 http://www.hrpub.org/download/20140305/MS7-13401470.pdf or http://www.jiem.org/index.php/jiem/article/viewFile/60/27.  I don't think scipy works since one needs to write loss in tensor operations.

Comment: @KotaMori I think you're right that I'm looking for an approximation of the CDF.  Thanks for the links.  I also found http://m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2014/ams-85-88-2014/epureAMS85-88-2014.pdf.  Any suggestions for how to pick an approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use TensorFlow as your Keras backend, you could leverage [tf.distributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions) to compute the CDF of the normal distribution:

```
from tensorflow.distributions import Normal

def probit(x):
    normal = Normal(loc=0.,
                    scale=1.)
    return normal.cdf(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with another problem related to approximating a normal CDF / inverse-normal CDF. The latter is also called quantile funxtion, probit function or percent point function, which can be found in scipy. So this may be just what you needed a few months ago. :)

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.ppf(x,0,1)
```